# How to get enable Glip Create Data Export Task API access rights?

Tags: permissions, ringcentral, glip

I received the following Access Rights error when attempting to create a Glip Compliance Export. How can I get these access rights / permissions?

- Glip Create Data Export Task API

  - https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Glip-Compliance-Exports-createDataExportTask

Request:

```
POST https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/glip/data-export
Authorization: Bearer <myToken>

{
  "userIds":[
    "11111111"
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
403 Forbidden

{
  "errors":[
    {
      "errorCode":"GIC-012",
      "message":"Access rights to data export required."
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Compliance Exports API requires the authorized user be a Glip Administrator with the Compliance Export permission.

To enable this permission, have an administrator:

1. click bring up the Glip Administration console in the web app
2. add the desired API user as an Administrator
3. add the permission by navigating to the "Compliance Exports" section and adding the user under "Who can request and download exports"

Read more in this article which also includes screen shots:

https://medium.com/ringcentral-developers/glip-compliance-exports-api-for-ediscovery-gdpr-and-analytics-d140783527f5